# TableView with prototype cells that contain collectionview not returning all the tableviewcells

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

So I have a TableViewController that has a tableview with currently 4 prototype cells. Each prototype cell has a collectionview in them and that collectionview has collectionviewcells. I am trying to get the tableview to display the separate tableview cells with the collectionview in them but so far with my code it is only returning the first tableview cell and not the rest. This is my first time trying to use a collectionview inside of a tableview so I'm sure it is something small I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class AlbumSongArtistTableViewController: UITableViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         if section == 0 {
                   return 1
               } else if section == 1 {
                   return 1
               } else if section == 2 {
                   return 1
               } else {
               return 1
            }
        }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GenresTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! GenresTableViewCell


            return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeaturedArtistsCollectionViewTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FeaturedArtistsCollectionViewTableViewCell

            return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 2 {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewReleasesCollectionViewTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! NewReleasesCollectionViewTableViewCell

            return cell
        } else {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SomthingElseCollectionViewTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SomthingElseCollectionViewTableViewCell

            return cell
        }
    }

    //MARK:- collection view delegate

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
                          return 10
                      } else if section == 1 {
                          return 8
                      } else if section == 2 {
                          return 6
                      } else {
                      return 4
                   }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0{

            let cell:GenresInsideTableViewCellCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "GenresInsideTableViewCellCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! GenresInsideTableViewCellCollectionViewCell

            return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {

        let cell:FeaturedArtistsInsideTableViewCellCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FeaturedArtistsInsideTableViewCellCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FeaturedArtistsInsideTableViewCellCollectionViewCell

        return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 2 {
            let cell:NewReleasesInsideTableViewCellCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "NewReleasesInsideTableViewCellCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! NewReleasesInsideTableViewCellCollectionViewCell

            return cell
        } else {
            let cell:SomethingElseInsideTableViewCellCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SomethingElseInsideTableViewCellCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SomethingElseInsideTableViewCellCollectionViewCell

            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what my storyboard looks like:

[image: StoryBoard]

Here is what my simulator looks like when I run it:

[image]

UPDATE: Here is what my code looks like for my tableviewcell sublcass:

```
import UIKit

class FeaturedArtistsCollectionViewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var faCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}

extension FeaturedArtistsCollectionViewTableViewCell {

    func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate
        <D: UICollectionViewDelegate & UICollectionViewDataSource>
        (_ dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row:Int)
    {
        faCollectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
        faCollectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate

        faCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented `numberOfSections` for your table view?  If. It, it will only have 1 section.

Comment: @Paulw11 so I implement this code `override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 4 }` but then it throws an error when I run it. The error is `could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier` which is confusing me because all of my collectionviews show they are connected on my storyboard to their respective collectionviewcell subclass

Comment: The section number in your collection view data source method will always be 0 since it is the collection view section, not the table view section.  The table view cell should be the collection view cell data source, not the view controller. You can then assign the appropriate data to the table cell

Comment: @Paulw11 sorry mate, I'm not quite understanding what you mean. I have updated my question above to show you the code for one of my tableviewcell sublclasses and as you can see the collecionview datasource and delegate are set up there.

Comment: In your `cellForItemAt` you are making a decision based on the section number, but the section number will always be 0 because there is only one section in each collection view and a different collection view in each cell.

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok I get what you are saying. So I need to remove this line of code under `cellForItemAt`: `if section == 0 {
                return 10
                } else if section == 1 {
                    return 8
                } else if section == 2 {
                return 6
                } else {
                return 4
            }` and replace it with something like `return 1` then would that work? Because when I run that the error goes away but it is still only return one tableviewcell with one collectionviewcell.

Comment: @Paulw11 Sorry about this again mate I've just never had to insert a collectionview into a tableviewcell. Ive used multiple collectionviews on a single view controller with no problem but I'm stumped on this one